# NSMutableString appendFormat... adds spaces?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring

When trying to append to an NSMutableString with appendFormat - It adds spaces.

NSM is just an NSMutableString, att_1_variable & att_2_variable is NSString

```
[NSM appendFormat:@"<tagname att_1=\" %@ \" att_2=\" %@ \">", att_1_variable, att_2_variable];
```

The result is:

```
<tagname myattribute="  ContentOfVariable  " title=" ContentOfVariable  ">
```

Before passing in the strings I am doing:

```
    NSString* att_1_variable = [att_1_variable_orginal stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                  [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Is there any way around this?

Thanks
Regards
Christian

Comment: Could you show more code around the call? It is not clear what else is going on.

Comment: `appendFormat:` doesn't add extra spaces. Can you tell us what `NSM` is before `appendFormat:`, what it is afterwards and what you're expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding the spaces yourself, by including them in the format string. In C the escape sequence for a quotation mark is just `\"`, with no trailing (or leading) space. So you want:

```
[NSM appendFormat:@"<tagname myattribute=\"%@\" title=\"%@\">", 
                                 attributeVariable, titleVariable];
```

If there are spaces between the quotation marks and the variable contents after that then your input variables are padded with spaces. You can trim those with something like:

```
NSString *trimmedAttributeVariable = [attributeVariable
        stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

...

[NSM appendFormat:@"<tagname myattribute=\"%@\" title=\"%@\">", 
                                 trimmedAttributeVariable, ...
```

Which will trim spaces and tabs from both ends.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want the result to be

`<tagname myattribute="ContentOfVariable" title="ContentOfVariable">`

In that case, remove the excess spaces that were around the format specifiers as such:

```
[NSM appendFormat:@"<tagname myattribute=\"%@\" title=\"%@\">", attributeVariable, titleVariable];
```

Comment: Sorry, Tommy came in 1 min before :-) Thanks you guys rock... Regards

Comment: While technically 13 seconds or so, he deserves it :)
Cheers.